# How do I target each image seperately, and fetch API data from them, instead of collect it all at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I've created an app that connects to an API that retrieves dog images. On page load, 12 images are displayed, along with json text, that provides information about the breeds; height of the dog etc.

My final step would be somehow connecting the a button (which already exists) to each individual image, then retrieving data for that one specific dog/image after clicking it, instead of the API fetching all of the data at once on initial page load.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import './Dog.js';
import './index.css';
import FetchAPI from './FetchAPI';




function DogApp() {

  return (
    
    <div className="dogApp">
     <FetchAPI />   
    </div>
  );
}

export default DogApp;
```

FetchAPI.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const FetchAPI = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const apiGet = () => {
        const API_KEY = "";
        fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=12&page=10&order=Desc?API_KEY=${API_KEY}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
                //setData([...data,json]); if json is single object
                setData([...data, ...json]); // if json is array of one object then use this line
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {           //call data when pagee refreshes/initially loads 
        apiGet();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <div class="dog">
                    <img src={item.url}></img>
                    <button onClick={item.breeds}>Fetch API</button>
                </div>
            ))}
            {data.map((item) => (
                <p>{JSON.stringify(item.breeds)}</p>
            ))}


            {/*<pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre> */}
            <br />


        </div>

    )
}

export default FetchAPI;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an other function which will fetch new (single) image and change it to the state as I have made function named apiGetSingle which changes the data on specific index. And if you have made the route as I have mentioned in apiGetSingle which will return single new image then it will work fine otherwise made backend route for that too.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const FetchAPI = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const apiGet = () => {
    const API_KEY = "";
    fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=12&page=10&order=Desc?API_KEY=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            //setData([...data,json]); if json is single object
            setData([...data, ...json]); // if json is array of one object then use this line
        });
};
 const apiGetSingle = (index) => {
    const API_KEY = "";
    fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?API_KEY=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            let d=[...data];
            d[index]=json; // if json is single object.
            d[index]=json[0] // if json returns array
            setData(d);
 };

useEffect(() => {        
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        {data.map((item,index) => (
            <div class="dog">
                <img src={item.url}></img>
                <button onClick={()=>apiGetSingle(index)}>Fetch API</button>
            </div>
        ))}
        {data.map((item) => (
            <p>{JSON.stringify(item.breeds)}</p>
        ))}

        <button onClick={apiGet}>Fetch API</button>
        {/*<pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre> */}
        <br />


    </div>

)
}

export default FetchAPI;
```

Comment: Thank you Asad, this is great! I would also like to know how to retrieve the json data from a certain dog image, instead of replace it with a new image, if that makes sense?

So with the 12 images that already load, I want to connect the button to retrieve the json data, only once I've clicked the Fetch API button, instead of it displaying on page load.

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Add a button and attach apiGet function on their click.

Comment: Attached the latest code for API fetch call only on button click and removed function call from useEffect.

Comment: And the first one I did not understand what you want to say "I would also like to know how to retrieve the json data from a certain dog image, instead of replace it with a new image"

Comment: Thank you for the help! and I apologize, I didn't explain properly the first time.